# Decompressing AVI file using DirectShow filters

Tags: c#, video-processing, directshow.net

I am trying to decompress an AVI file using DirectShow filters.

Here is the graph I am building.

File Reader -> AVI Splitter -> AVI decompressor -> SampleGrabber ->AVI Mux -> File Writer

I am suing SampleGrabber to report progress of conversion, nothing else.

The issue that I am having is that once the file is converted there is no audio in it. Video is all ok, but there is no Audio. I have tried the same set of filters using GraphEdt and it converts ok (Both Audio and Video are intact).

I really don't know what might be going wrong in this whole process. Any ideas?

I am using DirectShowNet

Comment: What is the audio media type in the AVI container? Do you have a decoder for the audio media type?

Comment: I do have decoders, because GraphEdt is able to to convert it. My program has the same filters, but somehow the resulting video do not have audio. I can post the code if you want me to.